# Difficulty implementing Equals Operator

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, logical-operators

I have two Parse generated `objectId` strings that I know are equal, because I print them out and read them, and they are the same.

They are `requestedUserId` and `requestingUserId`.

I have tried as mentioned in the comments to check for invisible characters

```
console.log('"' + requestedUserId + '"')
console.log('"' + requestingUserId + '"')
```

However, as suspected, they print out equal.

The code below never runs, it jumps to the `else` statement. Is there a problem with my logic, or anything else that is readily apparent?

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("FriendRequest", function(request, response) {

  var requestedUserId = request.object.get("to")
  var requestingUserId = request.object.get("from")

  console.log('"' + requestedUserId + '"')
  console.log('"' + requestingUserId + '"')     

  // One cannot request oneself
  if (requestedUserId == requestingUserId) {
    console.log("can't send a request to yourself")
    response.error("can't send a request to yourself");

  } else {
    (...)
  }
});
```

Comment: Well, how is it that you're so certain that the strings are the same, given that the computer thinks they aren't?

Comment: @Pointy because I chose to not include my `console.log` statements that print out the strings

Comment: Have you tried `===`?

Comment: What's up with the downvotes?????????? This is a legit question with code, description, and clear question

Comment: @ImmanuelValle I actually have! And that didn't work either

Comment: Are you sure there aren't any spaces. I like to do something like this on my console.log statements `console.log('"' + myvariable + '"')`. This way I can see any spaces.  If the code is running to else, then requestedUserId and requestingUserId are not equal.

Comment: Just a hunch, is there whitespace or perhaps certain `\n` or `\r` characters that may mess up your string even though it looks legit?

Comment: Well, I didn't vote but you're claiming that you know that two strings are equal even though the `==` tells you otherwise, so something is missing. What have you done to debug?

Comment: @Robbert ok so there's no syntax error ?

Comment: @ray, not sure I know what you mean.

Comment: A syntax error would cause the code to not run at all.

Comment: Change the `console.log()` calls to wrap the strings in some sort of marker characters so that you can see invisible strings. Note that string comparison is case-sensitive.

Comment: Have you checked the `length` of the the 2 strings that look the same in your console?

Comment: Are the IDs numeric? If they are strings are they the same case?

Comment: @robbert they are alphanumeric, they are the same case

Comment: Can you show us the output of the console.log for both. Something is not adding up here.

Comment: ray, you were asked by Xotic750 if you checked the `.length` of each string. Have you? If they're equal, then you may need to iterate over the characters in one string, and compare each character to the character at the same index in the second string.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, I suggest that you check the `length` of the 2 strings rather than relying on visibility in your console.

```js
var str1 = 'abc123';
var str2 = 'abc123' + String.fromCharCode(0);
console.log('"' + str1 + '"', str1.length);
console.log('"' + str2 + '"', str2.length);
console.log(str1 == str2);
```